# Screen embedded USB hub gets disconnected randomly

Tags: usb, disconnect

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 connected to an external screen via USB-C. This screen includes a USB hub, on which I connect a mouse, a keyboard and a headset. From time to time, this hub gets disconnected: none of the USB devices still work, while the video signal is still seen by the screen. Unplugging/replugging the USB-C cable solves the issue for some time (sometimes for hours, sometimes for a few seconds).

I tried to force `/sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend` to -1 but it didn't solve the problem (someone had suggested this trick for USB devices being disconnected).

In `dmesg`, I saw one error that may be related to this issue but I am not completely sure:

```
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Requester ID)
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:9d10] error status/mask=00100000/00014000
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [20] UnsupReq               (First)
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:   TLP Header: 34000000 01000010 00000000 08468680
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: device recovery failed
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pci_bus 0000:02: Allocating resources
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:02:01.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 04-38] add_size 1000
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:02:02.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 39] add_size 1000
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:02:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 39] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:01:00.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 02-39] add_size 3000
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:01:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x3000]
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:01:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x3000]
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:01:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x3000]
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:01:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x3000]
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:02:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:02:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:02:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:02:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:02:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:02:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:02:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[jeu. juil.  6 19:04:19 2023] pcieport 0000:02:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
```

Any clue would be more than welcome.